# Reference variable confusion

Tags: java, equals

```
class Test {

    String name;
    Test(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test t1 = new Test("Rakesh");
        Test t2 = new Test("Rakesh");
        System.out.printLn(t1 == t2);
   }
}
```

it gives the output `false` because t1 and t2 have two different objects and  it ==
checks for only references. This is fine, but when I do this

```
t1=t2;
```

Tlthe output returns `true`.

The question is, `t1` and `t2` are two new objects of class `Test` and created by `new` keyword. So how could its references equal?

Answer (score 1):

When you assign `t1=t2` both references refer to the same object (the second object you created in `Test t2 = new Test("Rakesh");`), so `t1==t2` becomes true.

After the assignment, the object that was created by `Test t1 = new Test("Rakesh");` no longer has references to it, which means it can be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

`t1=t2` means that the `t1` and `t2` both point to the same object.i.e `t1` now points to or stores the reference of the object pointed to by `t2`. So both `t1` and `t2` now point to the same object. So their references are equal.

Answer (score 0):

When you do t1 = t2, you are assigning the object t2 into the object t1, therefore making them the same object. It doesn't matter if you before created them both as independent objects with the new keyword.

Essentially, you're discarding the object that was created in t1 originally when you assigned t2 into it.